# Definite integral doubt

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm starting to study Calculus now, I've got the following problem:

What's the minimum value of $\displaystyle F(a) = \int_{0}^{2} |x^2 - a^2|\, \mathrm{d}x$

When $0 < a < 2$, I managed to find $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{a}-(x - a)(x+a) \,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{a}^{2} (x - a)(x + a) \,\mathrm{d}x$

It ends up with $\dfrac{4}{3}x^3-2a^2 + \dfrac{8}{3}$. Using differentiation to find maximum and minimum values of the function, I got $F'(a) = 4a^2 - 4a$, thus, the minimum value is $F(1) = \dfrac{4}{3} - 3 + \dfrac{8}{3} = 2$

I don't know how to proceed when the intval changes to $a >= 2$.

EDIT: There was a silly bug in my integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0\le a\le 2$, then your work is good, but it's better to write it

$$
F(a)=\int_0^a (a^2-x^2)\,dx +\int_a^2 (x^2-a^2)\,dx
$$

so with easy computations you find $F(a)=(4a^3-6a^2+8)/3$.

If $a>2$, then $|x^2-a^2|=a^2-x^2$, for $x\in[0,2]$. Thus
$$
F(a)=\int_0^2(a^2-x^2)\,dx=
\left[a^2x-\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_0^2=
2a^2-\frac{8}{3}
$$

Note now that $F(-a)=F(a)$, so there's no need to study the function for $a<0$: if you find a minimum at some point $a_0\ge0$, then you'll have one at $-a_0$ and conversely.

The complete definition (for $a\ge0$) is then
$$
F(a)=\begin{cases}
\frac{4a^3-6a^2+8}{3} & \text{for $0\le a\le 2$}\\[2ex]
\frac{6a^2-8}{3} & \text{for $a>2$}
\end{cases}
$$

Note that $F$ is continuous at $2$.

Let's compute the derivative:
$$
F'(a)=\begin{cases}
\frac{12a^2-12a}{3} & \text{for $0\le a < 2$}\\[2ex]
\frac{12a}{3} & \text{for $a>2$}
\end{cases}
$$
or, simplifying,
$$
F'(a)=\begin{cases}
4a(a-1) & \text{for $0\le a < 2$}\\[2ex]
4a & \text{for $a>2$}
\end{cases}
$$
and we can supplement this with $F'(2)=8$, because the limit of the derivative exist.

The derivative is negative for $0\le a<1$ and positive for $a>1$. Thus $1$ is the point where $f$ assumes its minimum value.

Since $F(1)=2$, this is the minimum for the function.

At the point $0$, $F$ has a relative maximum.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply write the integral, assuming $a \in [0,2]$, as

$$\int_0^a dx (a^2-x^2) + \int_a^2 dx (x^2-a^2) = \frac{4}{3} a^3 - 2 a^2 + \frac{8}{3}$$

You can show that $a=1$ is the minimum. (You can see this from the second derivative.)